# A long stored procedure stops returning results after some execs, why?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi
I've a long stored procedure which is used to populate a GridView in my asp.net(c#) application and another console application(c#). Every time I run this sp on management studio it works fine. Some days this sp stops returning values to applications (but at the same time works fine when executed from management studio). Why or how can this happen? (I'm using ms sql 2005 and win server 2003)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much detail but I would guess that you are getting timeout errors and you have a parameter sniffing issue (running fine in SSMS but not from applications is normally a bit of a give away for this.)

Next time the issue arises such that it doesn't work from your application but works fine from SSMS use the following query to retrieve both plans and compare.

```
Use YourDatabase;

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) 
cross APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(plan_handle) AS epa
where sys.dm_exec_sql_text.objectid=object_id('YourProcName') 
         and attribute='set_options'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I just do an alter proc_name without any changes to sp, problem is solved. and you are right it is giving timeout

Comment: Altering the procedure will drop the execution plan so that would again indicate parameter sniffing as the fault.